# Create collections in cloudant

Tags: ionic-framework, couchdb, pouchdb, cloudant

I'm trying to build an ionic application which retrieves data from Cloudant using pouchdb. Cloudant allows creating only databases and documents.
How can I create some collections in Cloudant?

Comment: I'm sure it depends on what you mean by "collection". Can you clarify, perhaps by reference to another database that provides collections which match the functionality you desire?

Answer (score 1):

Two part answer:

A set of documents that meet certain criteria can be considered a collection in Cloudant/CouchDB. You can create [views](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/creating_views.html#views-mapreduce-) to fetch those documents. Such a view might check for the existence of a property in a document ("all documents with a property named *type*"), the value of a property ("all documents with a property named *type* having the value of *book*") or any other condition that makes sense for your application and return the appropriate documents.

You basically have to follow a three step process:

- determine how you can identify documents in your database that you consider to be part of the collection
- create a view based on your findings in the previous step
- query the view to retrieve those documents

Above documentation link provides more details.

Properties in your document can represent collections as well, as in the following example, which defines a simple array of strings.

```
{
  "mycollectionname": [
      "element1",
      "element2",
      ...
  ]
}
```

How you implement collections really depends on your use-case scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Long post, but hope that helps.

I would like to explain this with a RDBMS analogy.

In any RDBMS, a new database would mean a different connection with different set of credentials.
A collection would mean the set of tables in that particular database.
A record would mean a row in a table.

Similarly, you can look at a single Cloudant service instance as a database(RDBMS terminology).
A collection would be a "database" in that service instance in Cloudant's terminology.
A document would correpond to a single row.

Hence, Cloudant has no concept of collection as such. If you need to store your related documents in a separate collection you must do it with multiple databases within the same service instance.

If you want to use only a single database, you could create a field like "record_index" to differentiate between the different documents. While querying these documents, you could use an index. For. e.g. I have a student database. But I do not want to store the records for Arts, Commerce, Science branches in different databases. I will add a field "record_type": "arts", etc. in the records. Create an index,

```
{ selector: {record_type: "arts"}}
```

Before doing any operation on the arts records, you can use this index and query the documents. In this way, you will be able to logically group your documents.